# Is it possible to keep a Reactstrap modal from unmounting before it has closed?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactstrap

I have a component that contains a Reactstrap modal. When the modals function is completed a toggle function is called. In addition, the modal is no longer mounted because a different component should be shown. Unfortunately, this leads to the modal vanishing instead of transitioning. I am looking for the best way to keep it mounted until the transition is finished.

Here is the code used to unmount
(LoginModal is the modal that is getting unmounted)

```
render() {
    const { isAuthenticated} = this.props;

    const authLinks = (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav navbar>

        </Nav>

        <Nav navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <Logout></Logout>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Fragment>
    );

    const guestLinks = (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem>
            <LoginModal></LoginModal>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Fragment>
    );

    return (
      <Navbar>
          {isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
```

Comment: can you provide some code about how you unmount it?

Comment: @JatinParmar I added some of the code to the original post

Comment: please check the answer , hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

this is because when you get authorized instead of closing the modal using 
isOpen=false you are directly removing it from the parent component
you should pass isOpen from parent to login modal like this

```
render() {
const { isAuthenticated} = this.props;

let authLinks=null;
let isOpen=false;

if(!isAuthenticated)isOpen=true;//we need to show login when user is not logged in
if(!isOpen){
    //when user is not logged in we will create nav link
    authLinks = (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav navbar>
        </Nav>
        <Nav navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <Logout></Logout>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Fragment>
    );
}
//instead of not rendering when authenticated,you should pass isopen=false
//here isOpen from login modal will be passed to react strap modal
//isOpen=false will cause dialog modal to close with transition
const loginModal = (
        <LoginModal isOpen={isOpen} ></LoginModal>
);

return (
  <Navbar>
      {loginModal}
      {authLinks}
    </Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);
}
```

you can read further [here](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question,  `isAuthenticated ` should not open/close the modal but instead, show/hide the button that toggles the modal.

Comment: @GICMan yes but as per your code one may no lead this perception